# Create and distribute archives remotely

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

i'm currently working as an iOS developer but where i live the internet speed is very low. So i'm looking for a way to build archives on a remote server and distribute them using that same server (located at somewhere with a decent internet connection) so i can distribute builds to testers on a faster way

i've already found some platforms like [xcloud.me](https://xcloud.me), [jekins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) or [Mac OS Server](https://www.apple.com/es/macos/server/) but i'm not sure if those platforms could make what i need

It is possible? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could either rent a macOS server [in the Cloud somewhere](https://xcloud.me) and setup your own solution (via [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org) for example) or use a SaS solution like [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.com) or [CircleCI](https://circleci.com).
Setting up your own solution on a macOS server is a considerable effort, so if you are new to Continuous Integration, Continuous Delivery and Administration it is probably a good idea to use a SaS solution. A full setup could look like this:

1. Host your code on GitHub or similar
2. Use [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.com) or [CircleCI](https://circleci.com) to build your app
3. Upload the build to a distribution service like [HockeyApp](https://www.hockeyapp.net) for distribution